# Prestashop - how do we can check the date/time when product came back in stock

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-modules

I am working on a Prestashop website. where i need to check when the procust came in stock. so i can proceed further.

e.g.
Product name is "Black shirt" and is currently out of stock.

- "Black shirt" now came in stock on the date 22-march-2021. is there any way i can get date( 22-march-2021) when "Black shirt" came in stock last time.
- when it will be out of stock in future. and came back in stock again. let's say it will be back in stock on date "10-may-2021". then i need to get the date "10-may-2021".

In case of any suggestion, feel free to share.

Thanks

Comment: If you need some history you'll need to interact with the Stock class
or perform a direct query to ps_stock_mvt table.
There you can find all stock operations for a given product with related date
of modification.

Comment: Thanks for the response, From there will get date but even i change anything other than quantity. My requirement is to get date when quantity is getting udated. @user3256843

Comment: Why do you say this? the purpose of the table I suggested is to only save the stock movements.
the general update date of the product is in ps_product / ps_product_shop (date_add field)